# Janus RTP_Forward, Gstreamer and streaming it into html5 browser

Tags: gstreamer, rtp, janus

Janus has feature to forward rtp, and so i've made listener with gstream with this command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 --gst-debug=4 rtpbin name=rtpbin -v udpsrc port=5104 caps="application/x-rtp, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=100" ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

The question is how can i show it into html5 browser?